# Link files and directories, in target directory, with cross-device links

Tags: symlink, hard-link

I have a user account at my local library (they use [openslx](https://www.openslx.org)), in which I can store files. My actual home folder is "mounted" (I'm not sure how) in `/home/[my_userID]/PERSISTENT` instead of `/home/[my_userID]`.

After logging in, an `xterm` window is started, the window manager is [openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page). With logging out, everything not stored in `PERSISTENT` is deleted in `/home/[my_userID]`. (The complete message is shown below.)

When I change the configs of `mousepad`, e. g., the config file is stored in `/home/[my_userID]/PERSISTENT/.config/Mousepad` and I have to copy the file(s) manually for storing my configuration for the next session.
To solve this, I've copied all the dotfolders from `PERSISTENT` to `$HOME` right after every login, but I'm sure there's a faster and way more elegant way to deal with this issue.

Is there a way to link to the dirs with a single entry in `.bash_history` ("command")?

```
ATTENTION: This is the non-persistent home directory!
Files saved here will be lost on shutdown.
Your real home is under /home/sj126/PERSISTENT
Please save your files there.
```

Comment: The question makes sense, but I don't get the title. What is the write-permissions about? It also does not match your goals, it seems to summarise the solution.

Comment: I really had trouble finding a (proper) title. If anyone could find a better one…?

Comment: I make an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I've figured out that I could use symbolic links to speed up the configuration thing at least.

```
rm -dfr .cache .config .local&&ln -fs PERSISTENT/.bash_aliases PERSISTENT/.bash_history PERSISTENT/.bash_logout PERSISTENT/.cache PERSISTENT/.config PERSISTENT/.ICEauthority PERSISTENT/.local PERSISTENT/.ssh PERSISTENT/.vim PERSISTENT/.viminfo PERSISTENT/.vimrc PERSISTENT/.xinputrc PERSISTENT/.xsession-errors ~&&openbox --reconfigure&&gnome-terminal&exit
```

The command first deletes default dirs in `/home/[my_userID]` to bypass/circumvent a write error due to creating a link with the same destination/path (`/home/[my_userID]/.config`, e. g.) as an existing directory or file.

Second, the symlinks are created. This changes neither the behaviour or appearance of the session, nor that of programs (`mousepad`, e. g.).

Third, the window manager gets the new configuration, which is also stored in `/home/[my_userID]/PERSISTENT/.config`.

Fourth, a terminal with tabbing is started for a more comfortable session usage and the no more needed instance of `xterm` is terminated. Mind the single `&` in front of `exit`. A double one would exit your `xterm` not until your `gnome-terminal` is terminated.

To use this command, just store it in your `/home/[my_userID]/PERSISTENT/.bash_history` as your first command. Watch out to have an unlimited `HISTFILESIZE` in your `/home/[my_userID]/PERSISTENT/.bashrc` or a way larger one than you will need. Otherwise, the command will be lost when your maximum history size is reached. Having a time stamp for this command is optional.

I'm not sure right now wether you can easily change your configs with `ln -s` or wether you need `ln` for getting write permissions to your config files.

Comment: Using `ln -f` unfortunately doesn't work (but would let me change the config files directly in the programs without touching the files themselves) because the underlying folder `PERSISTENT` is located on another device, which leads to the error messages `ln: failed to create hard link '/[…]' => 'PERSISTENT/[…]': Invalid cross-device link` and `ln: PERSISTENT/[…]: hard link not allowed for directory`. So this solution seems pretty close although there's still some effort to make to solve the issue